# Replace null with zero in crosstab query in Telerik

Tags: sql, telerik, reporting

I just created 2 cross table using wizard function of Telerik Standalone report designer tool

since ISCED 5 has values for private and public its showing properly

[image: cross table 1]

using same query I created second cross tab and

but since ISCED 6 table doesnt have values for "public" section its showing like this
[image: cross table 2]

how to show as zero for public section 2nd cross tab (when no values for specific row)

Comment: It is quite rude to ask questions and then ignore completely who tried to help you. At least reply if the solution worked for you.

Comment: thnks lot @FeliceM but when I put this expression it gives same results = Iif(Fields.Type_of_HEI IS Null OR Fields.Type_of_HEI = "Public" OR Fields.Type_of_HEI = "Private", "0", Fields.Type_of_HEI)

Answer (score 1):

You should modify the value of the field using an expression to evaluate your condition.

1. Select the textbox containing the data corresponding to the column you like to format when the value is null.
2. In the property pan on the right select "Value"
3. Write in there your expression, it should be something like this:

   ```
   =Iif(Fields.MyField IS Null,"0",Fields.MyField)
   ```

You should also consider if the value instead of null is empty and eventually cover this case in the expression if applicable.

```
    = Iif(Fields.MyField IS Null OR Fields.MyField = "", "0", Fields.MyField)
```

More information on conditional formatting can be found [here](http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/expressions-evaluation-flow-functions.html).

Let us know if this works for you.

Comment: thnks 

but when I put this expression it gives same results

= Iif(Fields.Type_of_HEI IS Null OR Fields.Type_of_HEI = "Public" OR Fields.Type_of_HEI = "Private", "0", Fields.Type_of_HEI)

Comment: @kez Show your query.